# How to set the minimum date properly and to get the minimum date that displayed on picker view?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

[image]

I have a pop up view controller like the picture above. In `viewDidLoad`, I set the minimum date for picker view is now ( Date() ), and in storyboard, I set the interval time in 15 minutes. here is the code I use

```
class DateTimePickerVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var dateTimePickerView: UIDatePicker!

    var selectedDateAndTime : Date?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // to make live update of selected date
        dateTimePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DateTimePickerVC.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

        // minimum date is now
        dateTimePickerView.minimumDate = Date()

        // set initial value, to avoid nil value
        selectedDateAndTime = dateTimePickerView.date


    }

    @objc func datePickerValueChanged (datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        selectedDateAndTime = datePicker.date
    }



    @IBAction func pickedButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // send date 'selectedDateAndTime' to other VC
    }

}
```

I have 2 problems in here:

1. let say the user open that pop up datePickerVC at 16:28. I expect the minimum date and time that will be displayed at that pop up will be "Today 16:30", but at my case is "Today 16:15". how to solve this issue?
2. to avoid nil value of `selectedDateAndTime`  , in `viewDidLoad` I set `selectedDateAndTime = dateTimePickerView.date`, so I hope that when the user immediately tap the save button and send the `date` to other VC without scrolling the date picker, it will get the minimum date that displayed in datePicker. let say the user open that pop up at 16:08, I expect the selected date to be the minimum date and time displayed at datePickerView (today 16:15), but the actual date value I get is (Today 16:08), because I set the `datePicker.minimumDate = Date()` (now). how to get the minimum date that displayed on datePicker view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum DateRoundingType {
    case round
    case ceil
    case floor
}


extension Date {
    func rounded(minutes: TimeInterval, rounding: DateRoundingType = .round) -> Date {
        return rounded(seconds: minutes * 60, rounding: rounding)
    }
    func rounded(seconds: TimeInterval, rounding: DateRoundingType = .round) -> Date {
        var roundedInterval: TimeInterval = 0
        switch rounding  {
        case .round:
            roundedInterval = (timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / seconds).rounded() * seconds
        case .ceil:
            roundedInterval = ceil(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / seconds) * seconds
        case .floor:
            roundedInterval = floor(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / seconds) * seconds
        }
        return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: roundedInterval)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//add below code in viewDidLoad()
let nextMinuteIntervalDate = Date().rounded(
    minutes: 15,
    rounding: .ceil
)
dateTimePickerView.minimumDate = nextMinuteIntervalDate
dateTimePickerView.setDate(nextMinuteIntervalDate, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you must be aware of the fact that why it is showing 16:15 as the time (16:28) is still logically less than 16:30 and I don't think you can do that as it doesn't make *any logical sense*
2. By the declaration of *`minimumDate`* :

> var minimumDate: Date? { get set }

As `minimumDate` has a ***get*** property, you can just fetch the *minimum date* using :

```
// Since it is an optional , we have to safe unwrap it 
if let minimumDate = datePicker.minimumDate {
   // Use your minimumDate variable here
}
```